# Write an I2C code for Cyclone 2 architecture

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii, cyclone

I really need to I2C interface my FPGA with some slave device. I figured I could use the audio codec in my FPGA as a slave.I have gone through some codes from the internet for I2C. But I do not get them.

To initiate a start sequence, What do I do? I know I want to drive SDL low while SCL is high. But I do not have much idea how I should code.

```
process(Start)

begin

if Start='0' then

   ACTIVE='0';

else

   SCL='1';

   SDL='1';

   SDL='0';

   ACTIVE='1'; 

end if;

end process;
```

Is this the way,my start sequence initiation should be? Should I add anything else?

Besides more importantly, How am I supposed to wait for an acknowledgement?

Comment: I hope this comment is not considered rude, but I think you should first learn how VHDL works and how it can be used to describe hardware. So you can take a class that teaches HDL 'programming' or read a book/tutorial. If you have solved to describe simple structures like counters, FSMs or decoders in hardware, you can try to describe more advanced modules for bus protocols like your requested I²C. Besides that, [OpenCores](http://www.opencores.org) has free I²C cores ready for use.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to what was said before, you can found I2C specification help on this:
http://i2c.info/i2c-bus-specification
and VHDL on https://www.eewiki.net/display/LOGIC/I2C+Master+(VHDL) . But take note that I2C can be customized to read/write different bytes and also with other features like clock stretching and oversampling clock so is better to write your code by yourself.